# Avoiding simultaneous sessions with requests.Session()?

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a medical journal's website (https://www.edimark.fr/, for which I am a paid subscriber) for links to PDF articles. Authentication is required to access the articles, and I have been able to login successfully using `requests.post`. My problem is that the site appears to be logging me out after requests gets 5 links (I can tell because when I test printing the HTML for each link, after 5 links my account name is replaced by the generic username). When I go to the website manually to log-in again, the site tells me that I cannot have over 5 simultaneous active sessions and that I must close one of these sessions to log in again. Even after I terminate the command, I can still not login for some time.

My question is: is there a way to get around this by restarting/logging out/terminating each session before the loop (shown below) reiterates to avoid being kicked off? Or is there any other solution? The code that I am using (with username and password hidden) is below. You can see that I am iterating the request through 14 links. I would think that running this under `with requests.Session() as s:` would have kept me logged in for the entire duration, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I have also included `s.get('https://www.edimark.fr/deconnexion')` (the logout url) at the end of the loop, but that doesn't seem to help either.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import sys

login_url = "https://www.edimark.fr/front/frontlogin/index"
base_url = 'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/14/page:'


payload = "data%5BUser%5D%5Bemail%5D=XXXXX&data%5BUser%5D%5Bpassword%5D=XXXXX&_method=POST"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
for i in range(1, 14):
    target_url = base_url +str(i)
    response = s.get(target_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    s.get('https://www.edimark.fr/deconnexion')
    print soup.text
```

Please note that I am *very* new to any sort of coding/programming, so forgive me if I am not using the correct verbiage. I'm sure that the code above isn't the most elegant either. Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated, preferably in simpler terms if at all possible.

Comment: you want to say that the site automatically log you off ?

Comment: Yes, it logs me off after 5 requests.

Comment: just to confirm, your `email/user` is usually in the `HTML` source?

Comment: Yes, it is when I get the `base_url`. When I print `soup.text` my username is shown for the first 5 iterations, but I am logged out after the fifth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Since i don't have a valid `email/pass` to validate my request.

We need to walk through together in order to catch the main `issue`

Kindly run the following code and let me know if you get `AssertionError` or not.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    '_method': 'POST',
    'data[User][email]': 'email@email.com',
    'data[User][password]': 'yourpassword'
}


def Login(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(url, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
        assert "email@email.com" in r.text


Login("https://www.edimark.fr/front/frontlogin/index")
```

> please replace `email@email.com` and `yourpassword` with your credentials.

Comment: I do get an assertion error here, but the login URL doesn't redirect anywhere, so it wouldn't show my username as present in r.text. I do see the username in the text when I get base_url. Again, my issue here isn't logging in, it's staying logged in when looping through more than 5 pages on this site

Comment: @FrankChlumsky the website is running `CAKEPHP` Cookie. as am trying to figure out to refresh the cookie `key` during your requests. please be patient and retry the code with my edit **allow_redirects=True**

Comment: Adding `allow_redirects=True` seems to have solved the problem and is keeping me logged in. Thanks so much!